# Use blade value inside a component

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

At the moment I can successfully display some generated content in my blade view by calling a variable with a key, like this:

```html
<div>
{{ $data['key'] }}
</div>
```

What I would like to achieve, is to reuse the key for a class name for example. The reason for that is that I want to easily access this content with JavaScript by using a selector. Something that would look like this:

```html
<div class='key'>
{{ $data['key'] }}
</div>
```

This code work, but as I have many fields, I would like to avoid duplicating the key. To achieve that, I thought of creating a blade components, and pass the key in the slot. So that I can reuse this key both in the class name, and in the placeholder for data.
But it seems that my variable `{{ $data }}` is not accessible from my component file, as it throws the error: `$data is undefined`.

Here is my code:

```html
<!-- In main.blade.php -->
@component('my-component')
key
@endcomponent
```

```html
<!-- In my-component.blade.php -->
<div class="{{ $slot }}">
{{ $data[$slot] }}
</div>
```

I am not familiar to Blade so I am open to another approach if necessary.

Comment: if you want ot use larvel component then you can pass data to component like    `@component('my-component',['keyname' => $data])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass your data and key as arguments to your component, thereby being more explicit. You don't need to use a slot for this, as a slot is generally used for blocks of text or HTML, not for simple attributes.

Create your component like this,

```html
<div class="{{ $key }}">
    {{ $data[$key] }}
</div>
```

And then render it like this

```
@component('my-component', ['data' => $data, 'key' => 'key'])
```